# Powershell script to update Network routes on multiple computers using PsExec tool

Tags: powershell

I want to add network route to multiple computers, but I can only use Local Admin credentials for the machines as there is no domain authentication. I cannot use `Invoke-Command` or `RemoteWMI` commands either.

I have a text file updated with all the computer Names
I have created another separate folder with multiple BAT files with individual commands to add route on the machines.

```
$computers = gc "C:\Users\Javed\Desktop\New\computers.txt"

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
if (test-Connection -Cn $computer -quiet) {
    & C:\Users\Javed\Downloads\PsTools\psexec.exe \\$computer -u "admin" -p "Password123" /accepteula "C:\Users\javed\Desktop\routes\$computer.bat"
} else {
    "$computer is not online"
}
}
```

I want to keep all the information Computer Name, Route Command in a single CSV/Excel Sheet like below and use it to add network routes, can anyone help here?

```
____________________________________________________________________
|HostName   |Commands                                               |
|___________|_______________________________________________________|
|_Computer1_|__route add -p 172.1.1.1 mask 255.255.255.255 172.2.2.2|
|_Computer1_|__route add -p 172.1.1.2 mask 255.255.255.255 172.2.2.2|
|_Computer1_|__route add -p 172.1.1.3 mask 255.255.255.255 172.2.2.2|
|___________|_______________________________________________________|
```

Comment: Have you tried to use DHCP option 121 to [push static routes](https://ercpe.de/blog/advanced-dhcp-options-pushing-static-routes-to-clients) to the workstations?

Comment: We dont have access to the DHCP , so can't use that option